# kendoui mobile in phonegap error in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cordova, kendo-ui

I am working kendoui mobile in phonegap ,i have cerated html page display list of records from data base using wcf web api service it is working fine in android but in iphone i am getting error PhoneGapSample[1672:15503] ERROR whitelist rejection:

```
    url=''
```

help me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with xcode and PhoneGap. If you check out the [tutorial here](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-02-22/building_your_first_kendo_ui_mobile_phonegap_application.aspx) and scroll down to the "Wiring Up View Events" section, you will see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to whitelist the domain in Cordova.plist

Quote from Phonegap documentation: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

```
1. Open Cordova.plist.
   - In Xcode, it is found at AppName/Resources/Cordova.plist
   - In the directory, it is found at AppName/Cordova.plist

2. Add a new String value under the ExternalHosts key.
   - We recommend using Xcode to avoid editing raw XML.
   - Domain protocols (e.g. http:// and https://) are not supported by iOS.
```